# How do I save and see my saved Apple Music channels?

Tags: ios, music.app, itunes-radio, apple-music

I can't figure out how to save a channel in the new Apple Music app like I could with iTunes Radio in the old Music.app. Also I can't find my saved stations. The closest I can get to my saved stations is the recent stations list which isn't the same.